# ADODB.Stream ReadText not working properly

Tags: vba

I am trying to read a csv file line by line using ADODB.Stream. When I execute the .ReadText(-2) method it works properly for the first line but starts truncating initial 2 characters from all the next lines and doesn't read the last line.

Below is the code I have tried.

```
Set oTextStream = New ADODB.Stream

With oTextStream
    .Charset = "utf-8"
    .LineSeparator = adLF
    .Open
    .LoadFromFile (sFullPath)
End With

Do Until oTextStream.EOS
    Debug.Print oTextStream.ReadText(-2)
Loop
```

Instead of printing :
"Actuariale organisaties";"R12345"

It prints :
ctuariale organisaties";"R12345"

Comment: I don't think `ADODB.Stream` supports `utf-8`.

Comment: @Dai - It does. fso doesn't support utf-8. In fact I can get the code to work perfectly if I read the complete text using ReadText(-1) and split by vbLF. But it makes the code very slow for large files.

Comment: Could the line separator really be `adCRLF`?  A line feed without a carriage return is relatively rare in Windows.

Comment: @Comintern - I had tried that too, but same result. Well I sorted this out in a different way. I read the whole file and split it by the line separator character to get an array of lines. At least it does the job.

Comment: I do remember did this exactly one line at a time!

Comment: @KamleshKishor sorry but I don't understand how you solved it. I'm having the same issue reading line truncated.